# Dedekind cut for 1/x

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I’m kind of new to this concept and trying to get my head over it.

How do you construct a dedekind cut for $\frac{1}{x}$ where $x$ is a positive real number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$ A Dedekind cut is a partition of $\Q$ satisfying certain additional nice properties. So, one way you could do this (somewhat trivially) is by taking $A = \{a \in \Q \mid a < \frac{1}{x} \}$ and $B = \{b \in \Q \mid b \geq \frac{1}{x} \}$. Of course, this relies on the assumption that you already have $x$ defined.

Comment: Okay, I think I get this!

But what if I have a DC for x (something like $S= \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} |r<x \}$, I guess?) and then try to construct a DC using $S$? I thought of something like $S'= \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} |r\le 0$ or $\frac{1}{r}<\frac{1}{x}\}$ but I'm not sure whether it works

Comment: Sure, if you wanted to use $S$, I think $S' = \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid r \leq 0 \text{ or } \forall s \in S, s > 0  \implies r < \frac{1}{s}\}$ should work.